# How to access textblock inside Datatemplate in combobox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, combobox, datatemplate

I am trying to Bind the TextBlock inside ComboBox through Code. I am able to bind the textblock sucessfully but For some reasons TextBlock doesnt display Text Values.

I have mechanism which checks for the selected values and there I am getting the selected values without any problem.

So to conclude, My binding is working fine but I am missing out something hence textblock is not displaying text that is bound with it.

This is the code I am using for Binding:
where "lObjTextBlock" is TextBlock inside of ComboBox.

```
TextBlock lObjTextBlock = (TextBlock)ComboBox.ItemTemplate.LoadContent();

 Binding lObjBinding = new Binding();

lObjBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("[" + lObjMap.PropertyName + "]");

lObjTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, lObjBinding);
```

This is the XAML for the TextBlock:

```
<my:HComboBox Name="cmbRefDoctor">
<my:HComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtRefDoctorName" />
    </DataTemplate>
</my:HComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</my:HComboBox>
```

Once again : My problem is that TextBlock is not displaying any Text althought values are being set.

Would love to get all possible suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it's one of the way to bind controls which inside datatemplate

```
this.DataContext = Person;

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = ob;
DataTemplate dtemp = (DataTemplate)Resources["PointTemp"];
Border bdr = dtemp.LoadContent() as Border;
TextBlock tblk = bdr.Child as TextBlock;
tblk.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Here I used ob as double collection assign to textproperty by binding source

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PointTemp">
        <Border Margin="0,23,0,0" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Foreground="White" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And you can assign,

if it's combobox or listbox

Here Person is a class name, or set the class name in combobox itemsource